# How to write chinese character in pdf using itextAsian

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

```
BaseFont.AddToResourceSearch("iTextAsian.dll");
BaseFont.AddToResourceSearch("iTextAsianCmaps.dll"); //"STSong-Light", "UniGB-UCS2-H", 
BaseFont baseFT = BaseFont.CreateFont("STSong-Light", "UniGB-UCS2-H", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFT);
```

using this code I am getting error

> Font 'STSong-Light' with 'UniGB-UCS2-H' is not recognized.

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using and which version of iTextAsian? Starting with 5.2.x.y a different iTextAsian.ddl was used. If you use an older iTextSharp version with the newer iTextAsian.dll, you need to upgrade to a more recent iTextSharp version.

Comment: how can i add reference these DLL's?

Comment: I am not a C# developer. I only know Java. Please ask a C# developer if you are not a C# developer yourself. If you are a customer of iText, please contact support (we have C# developers on staff, not on StackOverflow).

Comment: in java how to use these dll's?

Comment: In Java one just adds a jar to the CLASSPATH.

Comment: i have added chinese font to my project it works fine

Comment: @sivaprakash I am having the same problem. Which Chinese fonts did you add? And how did you update your code to use it.